# Removing php from urls and force trailing slash

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, file-extension

I have asked this question before and used bits and pieces of code I did not understand and now its all falling apart. Hopefully I can get my intentions across more precisely than before. I am trying to learn regular expressions but I can't seem to apply what I have learned to mod-rewrite techniques.

My website has a lot of urls that end with `.php` at varying folder depths across the site. 
I would like all the urls to be `site.net/folder/folder/filename/` regardless of the amount of subfolders.

My problem is some of my forms use POST and GET request. So when a user clicks upload to upload a file I usually set the action part of a form to a `.php` file, for e.g `site.net/folder/script/upload.php` or `site.net/folder/folder/scripts/upload.php` usually handles the uploading of files before it redirects to `xyz` page.

When the .php urls are wiped out I am not able to find the upload scripts either. Can the mod-rewrite rules be structured to get the php extensions out without obstructing my 'worker' scripts (upload.php, processcontactinfo.php, etc)?
EDIT

This is what my script looks like so far.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST\ /([^.\ ]+\.)+php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /([^.\ ]+\.)+php(\?[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+/)*index/?$ http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^([^.]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]
RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.php [L]
```

I have tried different variations, but like I said I am not good at reading or creating the regular expressions. So it is mostly a trial and error effort at best. 
This allows me to access file files via site.net/folder/filename/ but it won't change a request from site/folder/filename.php to site.net/folder/filename/. Also at this point the various scripts cannot be found.

Comment: How would we solve your problem, if you don't show us your code, or at least formulate a proper question in English?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_sed.html - if you don't want to do that in PHP itself. So you can keep the rewrite rules (input URLs) and rewriting the URLs in your scripts output in one configuration place. But as commented, your question is much too broad, please be more specific and post your code / configuration and also what you tried so far.

Comment: I added the code I currently have in the .htaccess file. @ppeterka: not sure what I did not make clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove .php from URL and force a trailing slash /](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531909/remove-php-from-url-and-force-a-trailing-slash)

Comment: anubhava's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706737/remove-the-file-extension-php-using-htaccess-file removes all the .php extensions as desired but non of my forms are able to submit. I get my custom 404 page. Normally the forms would submit to a php page and then redirect accordingly. E.g If the form was supposed to call folder/upload.php the 404 message says folder/upload (not found) @ppeterka

Comment: You guys know any resources where I can learn some basics in this area?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you. you have to write this code on your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: When I use your code, if I enter this site.net/folder/filename it serves up the correct file without the extension. If I type site.net/folder/filename.php it serves up the file with the php extension. I need it to treat the file as a php file but don't show the extension.

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to treat the file as a php file but don't show the extension

Then you need to use this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUESTI} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /(.+)\.php($|\?|\ )
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [L,R=301]
```

Your original rules were close, except that conditions are always ANDed together, so there's no way the first two conditions can both be true. Also, conditions only apply to the immediately following `RewriteRule`, so your second `RewriteRule` gets applied **EVERY TIME**.

As for the rest of your rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http://www.site.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This may cause problems, since mod_dir *does exactly the opposite*, you may end up with a redirect loop. Note that mod_dir includes a trailing slash because of a [serious information disclosure security issue.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). So if you want to use the above rule, include a:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

to turn off mod_dir redirecting the browser to a URL *with the trailing slash*. As for the last bit, you're again running into the problem where you're trying to apply a `RewriteCond` to multiple `RewriteRule`'s. Both those conditions only apply to `RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]`, the last rule gets applied with no conditions at all. But if looks like you're trying to do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: I don't know how to start explaining what I have tried and what were the results. I feel as though you are teaching me to drive and I don't even know how to start the vehicle. I have been trying to get this to work for six months without any real progress. I am asking questions and not even show what I am really asking. I am going to get a proper book on regular expressions and some sound material on mod-rewrite apache etc. I won't bother to fix the urls until I can at least construct basic rules on my own. Sorry if I wasted your time. Thanks for you help.