# How to get My site url in folder system?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [remove .php extension with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess)

Rightnow my site url is like this:

```
www.viaviweb.com/about_us.php
```

i want this to appear like this:

```
www.viaviweb.com/aboutus
```

Comment: read about .htaccess and rewrite rule

Comment: Depends on what webserver you use.
If you use apache then have a look at rewrite rules.
E.g. http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove .php extension with .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4026021/remove-php-extension-with-htaccess) or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736591/remove-php-extension-from-url or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736591/remove-php-extension-from-url or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908122/removing-the-php-extension-with-mod-rewrite or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10706737/remove-the-file-extension-php-using-htaccess-file or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821222/remove-php-extension-explicitly-written-for-friendly-url

Comment: And many many more. Please use the search before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `RewriteRule` with the rewrite engine enable to do this. Create a empty file named `.htaccess` and put it in the base folder of your website and type this in to the file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^aboutus$    about_us.php [L]
```

Make sure to enable the `mod_rewrite` module in your Apache server in order to make this work properly. Read more about rewrite in Apache here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: -1. He may not have apache. Ok ok just kidding! My upvote to you. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create some rules in .htaccess, in you main folder you have a file named .**htaccess** (if it's not available you have to create one) and put these rules.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to remove .php extension using URL Rewriting / mod_rewrite](http://olimpsys.com/blog/how-to-remove-php-extension-using-url-rewriting-mod_rewrite/)

I hope this might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule about_us.php(.*)$ aboutus?$1 [L,QSA]
```